# Using FileStream without an actual file

Tags: c#, file, filestream

> I wanted to use the FileStream class to avoid saving any files on the
>   client's computer. But every constructor of FileStream requires a path
>   to a file.

**How do I create a FileStream from a stream and not have to save it on the harddrive?**

EDIT: *I am already using memorystream to store my information. But at some point I need to zip the files into ANOTHER STREAM. The problem is that the zip commands (I've looked in GZipStream - It zips FILES to a STREAM) require me a source filePath(FileStream).*

If I can't surpass by creating a FileStream from a stream, is there another way to zip streams?

Comment: FileStream IS to write to file, use MemoryStream instead

Comment: It is entirely incorrect to say that GZipStream processes *files*. It does not. It processes a byte-stream and doesn't care about files whatsoever. You need to explain your scenario more, perhaps showing exactly the code that wants a file. You can use GZipStream to work with arbitrary sources/destinations. You really need to explain what you are getting stuck on. If you "looked in GZipStream" and reached that conclusion, then you looked wrong.

Answer (score 16):

In this scenario you should just use a `MemoryStream`, and ensure your API just demands `Stream` rather than `FileStream` specifically. For example:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
     YourCode(ms);
}
```

Alternatively you could keep using `FileStream` by using a file in the temp area, via `Path.GetTempFileName()`.

Comment: the Path.GetTempFileName() helped

Answer (score 2):

You can either use other Stream types (like MemoryStream) or derive your own class from FileStream that will do nothing (or write wherever you need).

Answer (score 0):

FileStream works with files. You can't change this behaviour.

You may check other *Stream classes inherited from `System.IO.Stream` like [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).